# Adding an Overlay Div

Tags: css

I'm creating a full-screen design where:

- Top % Bottom bars are a specific height, but 100% width
- Middle Left Bar is specific width but 100% height
- Middle right bar takes up space of whatever is left

I'm trying to create an "options" div that would pop up from the bottom right bar, overlaying my map on the middle-right side.

[image]

However, by looking at my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/ABz3A/), you can see that what I did makes the options div start at the bottom div and goes downward. Furthermore, I gave it a 100% width, but it did not adapt the width of its container, but the width of the screen.

```
#options {
    position: absolute;
    background: #39E023;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give your div a `margin-top` which is equal to the height, negative:

```
#options {
    position: absolute;
    background: #39E023;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    text-align: right;
    margin-top: -200px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Madara, it does solve the positioning issue, however `width 100%` still makes the div go outside the screen.

Comment: Ahhh, the key was to set the position to relative!

Answer (score 1):

Just give the middle-right container `position:relative`, then set the options div to `left:0; bottom:0;`

I updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ABz3A/1/)

Comment: Thanks danwellman, however this positions the bar at the complete bottom left, covering the bottom bar.

Comment: hmm, doesn't seem to in the fiddle I linked to. Did you add `position:relative` to the appropriate container?

Comment: I swear, Firefox gets worse with every release. Looks perfect in Chrome and even IE8+